# LibreOffice Writer: How do we enable the grayed-out "Do not split paragraph" checkbox?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

In LibreOffice Writer 7.5.3.2, I created a new style. In the Text Flow panel for the style, I am not able to enable "Do not split paragraph"; it is grayed out.

I tried changing the style's inheritance parent to some other styles to no avail thinking it might be some inherited restriction. If that is the way, I didn't guess the right parent.

On page 110 of the *LibreOffice 7.5 Writer Guide*, there is a diagram of these settings also with the option grayed out. The text doesn't make any remarks about that state, sayinig only:

> *Use the Do not split paragraph option on the Text Flow tab of the Paragraph dialog (for individual paragraphs) or the Paragraph Style dialog (for all paragraphs with that style).*

I'm in the Paragraph Style dialog, in the Text Flow tab, as it says. It's grayed out, like the documentation shows in the figure on the same page.

Figure 71 in the document, on page 93, shows a Text Flow tab (supposedly from Paragraph settings, not Paragraph Style settings) where that box is not grayed out.

For what it's worth, if I select an instance of that style, and go into its Paragraph settings, the option is grayed out there also. Though even if that worked, I would want the option set at the style level.

Comment: Did you try searching the internet first before asking? I entered "libreoffice do not split paragraph" in a search engine and the second result gave a clear answer to this exact question.

Comment: @JimK I searched for `"libreoffice writer" "do not split paragraph" disabled` using Google. Somehow I didn't find it.  Today I can find it. Obviously I used the Internet; the documentation PDF didn't land onto my system off a CD-ROM catalog subscription.

Comment: It looks like the problem may have been the first pair of quotes. Those two terms aren't going to be adjacent in many cases. This query works well: `libreoffice writer "do not split paragraph" disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on my own. I think the developers intend for this to be a puzzle, so I'm protecting it with a spoiler concealer:

> You must uncheck the Window Control and Orphan Control checkboxes in the same tab, which are *below* that option.
>  Then the *Do not split paragraph* checkbox is enabled.
>  Those options control some related behaviors in a conflicting way with that option, and are mutually exclusive.
>  When you *Do not split paragraph*, those two options, in turn, become grayed out.
>  A hover tooltip could explain this, but then it wouldn't be a puzzle!
>  I have great idea for a puzzle game. You are shown a dialog box with 128 checkboxes. Some of them are grayed out, and are all in various states of being checked and unchecked. Your goal is to enable a particular goal option, `[ ] Make me Rich and Famous`. Each checkbox has an enabled or grayed-out state which is a secret Boolean function of the values of some (possibly all) the other checkboxes. So to enable the goal option, you have to get all the other options into the right state. But some of **those** options are grayed out too, so you have to figure that out.

Comment: "which are *below* that option" — as they should be, because if that box is checked, then the other boxes will be disabled. As explained at https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/writer-do-not-split-paragraph-disabled-how-to-re-enable/83015: "That makes sense, if you don’t want a paragraph to be split, you don’t get widows and orphans." Note: you wrote "Window" but it should be "Widow".

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of tooltips, because then it becomes a game of trying to figure out where to hover to find hidden information. On the other hand, I think ajlittoz's idea might be helpful — the box could be enabled and, if clicked, would cause both of the other boxes to become unchecked.

Comment: @JimK But, conversely, if either of the two boxes below are checked, then the above box is disabled.  Mutually exclusive UI elements that are on the same level of hierarchy must be radio boxes.   Problem here is that it's one versus a group of two: A XOR (B OR C).   That's solvable by radio boxes:  `Split protection:  { None (*); Simple Do Not Split ( ); Two-Option Nuanced Method:  Do A [ ] <param>, Do B [ ] <param> }`.  With suitable 2D layout. There are three exclusive choices, one of which has two additional subordinate checkboxes, with their additional parameters.

Comment: This question should be given a real answer for other people to read, so I'll add one.

Answer (score 0):

You must uncheck the *Widow Control* and *Orphan Control* checkboxes in the same tab. Then the *Do not split paragraph* checkbox is enabled.

As explained at https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/writer-do-not-split-paragraph-disabled-how-to-re-enable/83015:

> That makes sense, if you don’t want a paragraph to be split, you don’t get widows and orphans.

Related enhancement bug: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89714

Comment: I opened an enhancement: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156109